# Delete the word after 15 characters in PHP with white space support

Tags: php

I want to get the first 15 characters in this word with white space support.

```
$word = 'my word\n\nis this my word?\nMagnum\nwtwsetst.\nwtvet\n\n#rp';
```

should the result to be:

```
"my word

is thi..."
```

Comment: `var_dump(substr(str_replace('\n', "\n", $word), 0, 15));`

Comment: no, it don't support white space.

Comment: @JakeGould How can you mark a question as a duplicate of a question that's hold as unclear?

Comment: https://eval.in/145994 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `substr()` function.

```
$word = 'my word\n\nis this my word?\nMagnum\nwtwsetst.\nwtvet\n\n#rp';
echo substr(str_replace('\n', "\n", $word), 0, 15);
```

Although I see in one of your comments, you have said this doesn't preserve whitespace.
It will, but you're not seeing it.

If you're echoing this within/to HTML, which I presume you are, and you're not in `<pre>` tags, try converting line-breaks `\n` to `<br />`.

So try,

```
$word = 'my word\n\nis this my word?\nMagnum\nwtwsetst.\nwtvet\n\n#rp';
echo nl2br(substr(str_replace('\n', "\n", $word), 0, 15));
```

Comment: How can I add `...` after 15 characters?
`my word

is thi...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put string in `"` to escaped characters to work and use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function, Try this:

```
$word = "my word\n\nis this my word?\nMagnum\nwtwsetst.\nwtvet\n\n#rp";
echo substr($word, 0, 15);
```

[**Demo Link**](http://codepad.org/Wf6hFfHP)